# Отображение градиентной заливки текста в Safari

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть два `div`'а (их может быть больше) с изображением и текстом в каждом из них, причём текст плавно затухает сверху к низу.
Код `html`:

```
<div class="blog_entry">
    <div class="blog_entry_photo">
        <img src="..."></img>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_entry_text_wrap">
        <div class="blog_entry_title">...</div>
        <div class="blog_entry_text">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blog_entry">
    <div class="blog_entry_photo">
        <img src="..."></img>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_entry_text_wrap">
        <div class="blog_entry_title">...</div>
        <div class="blog_entry_text">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Код `css`:

```
.blog_entry {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.blog_entry_photo {
    border: 4px solid white;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;        
    position: relative; 
    vertical-align: top;   
}
.blog_entry_text_wrap {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.blog_entry_title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.blog_entry_text {    
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(2, 39, 2, 1), rgba(2, 39, 2, 0));    
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);/*transparent*/
    -webkit-background-clip: text;  
}
```

Во всех браузерах код отображается корректно кроме Safari. Возможность протестировать Safari есть только на IPad2. Некорректность заключается в следующем: плавное затухание текста есть только в первом `div`'е. Во втором текст не отображается вовсе и появляется только если тапнуть по экрану и потянуть вверх. То же проявляется и в crossbrowsertesting.com с выставленными параметрами. В чём может быть проблема?